# Express/mssql login form throws "ReferenceError:"" is not defined"

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, reactjs, express

I am creating a basic full stack login form but cannot for the life of my get this connected up properly.I have made a register with no issues. However when coming to the login it is killing me inside.

All I want to do is simply get the user to login from the front end (login class) which is then passed to my server.js and throw the query at the database to return whether the credentials exist (email and password ) and if they do to just simply redirect you to the home page if not a basic error .

This is the route from server.js

```
app.post("/login", function(req, response) {
  sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err + "initial connection");
      console.log(config.server);
    } else {
      try {
        var request = new sql.Request();

        var body = req.body;

        console.log(body);

        var Email = req.body.email;
        var Password = req.body.password;

        console.log(
          "this is the email" + Email,
          "this is the password" + Password
        );

        try {
          request.input("email", sql.VarChar, Email);
          request.input("password", sql.VarChar, Password);

          var queryString =
            "SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = @Email AND password = @Password";

          console.log("this is the query string " + queryString);

          request.query(queryString, function(err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            response.json(recordset);

            if (recordsets.Email.length > 0) {
              req.session.loggedin = true;
              req.session.email = email;
              response.redirect("/home");
            } else if (results.length < 0) {
              response.send("Incorrect email and/or Password!");
              console.log(err);
            }
          });

          // response.send("Please enter email and Password!");
          // response.end();
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          response.status(400);
          response.send(e);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        response.status(400);
        response.send(e);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This is my Login class

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { email: "", password: "" };
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.email.length < 8 || this.state.password.length < 8) {
      alert(`please enter the form correctly `);
    } else {
      const data = { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password };

      fetch("/login", {
        method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log("Success:", data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.email);
    console.log(this.state.password);
    return (
      <div>
        <Formik
          class="form-signin"
          action="auth"
          method="POST"
          initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log("Logging in", values);
              setSubmitting(false);
            }, 500);
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            email: Yup.string()
              .email()
              .required("Required")
              .matches(
                /(?=.*@)/,
                "This is not a  email address."
              ),

            password: Yup.string()
              .required("No password provided.")
              .min(8, "Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.")
              .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Password must contain a number.")
          })}
        >
          {props => {
            const {
              values,
              touched,
              errors,
              isSubmitting,
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              handleSubmit
            } = props;

            return (
              <form
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                class="form-signin"
                action="auth"
                method="POST"
              >
                <div className="jumbotron">
                  <h2>Login </h2>
                  <div className="help">
                    <Popup trigger={<Link> Help?</Link>} className="center">
                      <div>
                        Enter Codestone Email address and Password connected to
                        the account.
                      </div>
                    </Popup>
                  </div>

                  <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>

                  <input
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Enter your email"
                    value1={values.email}
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onInput={handleChange}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    className={errors.email && touched.email && "error"}
                  />
                  {errors.email && touched.email && (
                    <div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
                  )}
                  <label htmlFor="email">Password</label>
                  <input
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Enter your password"
                    value2={values.password}
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onInput={handleChange}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    className={errors.password && touched.password && "error"}
                  />
                  {errors.password && touched.password && (
                    <div className="input-feedback">{errors.password} </div>
                  )}

                  <button class="button" type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
                    Login
                  </button>
                  <p>
                    <Link to="/login"> Login Page </Link>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <Link to="/reset"> Reset Password </Link>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </form>
            );
          }}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Throughout the code I tried to implement as much logging as possible so that I could understand what everything was declared as (the ///// parts are me simply me trying to output the results from recordset which I hoped would be the result of the query ) The bottom line is the error itself.

```
Server running on port 5000
[0] { email: 'dfhf@.co.uk', password: '1234556789' }
[0] this is the emaildfhf@.co.uk this is the password1234556789
[0] this is the query string SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = @Email AND password = @Password
[0] ////////////////////undefined
[0] ////////////////////[object Object]
[0] ////////////////////[object Object]
[0] C:\Users\Henry Peters\Desktop\Vault\Newfolder(3)\Codestone-Desk-branch1\server.js:190
[0]             if (recordsets.Email.length > 0) {
[0]             ^
[0]
ReferenceError: recordsets is not defined
```

I am no longer receiving Reference error.
Updated server.js

```
app.post("/login", function(req, response) {
  sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err + "initial connection");
      console.log(config.server);
    } else {
      try {
        var request = new sql.Request();

        var body = req.body;

        console.log(body);

        var Email = req.body.email;
        var Password = req.body.password;

        console.log(
          "this is the email" + Email,
          "this is the password" + Password
        );

        try {
          request.input("email", sql.VarChar, Email);
          request.input("password", sql.VarChar, Password);

          var queryString =
            "SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = @Email AND password = @Password";

          console.log("this is the query string " + queryString);

          request.query(queryString, function(err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            response.json(recordset);
            console.log(recordset);

            if (recordset.email > 0) {
              console.log("made it into if stamtnet ");
              req.session.loggedin = true;
              req.session.email = email;
              response.redirect("/home");
            } else recordset.length < 0;
            //response.send("Incorrect email and/or Password!");
            console.log("stuck in the else " + err);
          });

          // response.send("Please enter email and Password!");
          // response.end();
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          response.status(400);
          response.send(e);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        response.status(400);
        response.send(e);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Now record set is correctly logged to console however the if statement never seems to work it will always print out "stuck in the else" This message was created by me but i honestly have no idea why even inputting the correct detail in will still make it go to the else.

I have tried multiple if statements as well as the one I have. 
The main one I want

```
 if (recordset.length > 0)
```

The ones I have tried also

```
if (recorset.email === Email)
if (recorset.email = Email)
if (recorset.email === Password)
if (recorset.email = Password)
```

Any help would be much appreciated this is the second day stuck on this issue :(

Comment: The error means that you're trying to use `recordsets` but you've never defined or declared it. It comes from nowhere and JS doesn't know what you expect this to be.

Comment: how would i define it so that the query results are stored here?

Comment: Isn't the query result held in `recordset` - no `s` at the end? Either add an `s` to that parameter or remove the final `s` from `recordsets`. It seems like it's a typo.

Comment: You are correct thank you . I am now getting same error I was getting earlier which is "LoginPage.js:41 POST http://localhost:3000/login 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: any ideas on how to resolve this

Comment: Can you update the question with the new error?

Comment: Just have for you ! :)

Comment: I am now stuck in the if

Comment: Can you show what displays this? ` console.log(recordset);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you always hit `stuck in the else` is because it is outside of the if else block.

I think you are using this [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) package.
Checking this package docs, I wrote a simpler and cleaner version of your code with come corrections.

```
app.post("/login", async (req, response) => {
  try {
    await sql.connect(config);

    var request = new sql.Request();
    var { Email, Password } = req.body;

    console.log({ Email, Password });

    request.input("email", sql.VarChar, Email);
    request.input("password", sql.VarChar, Password);

    var queryString = "SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = @Email AND password = @Password";

    const result = await request.query(queryString);

    if (result.recordsets[0].length > 0) {
      console.info("/login: login successful..");
      response.send("User logined");
    } else {
      response.status(400).send("Incorrect email and/or Password!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Err: ", err);
    response.status(500).send("Check api console.log for the error");
  }
});
```

Comment: This is still throwing errors. error 1 = " { Email: undefined, Password: undefined } "

Comment: error 2 = " Err:  ReferenceError: err is not defined"

Comment: error 3 = " (node:17044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Comment: This is now the new error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
index.js:1 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0"

Comment: EMAIL and PAssword still logged as undefined

Comment: @coderStew if you can send email and password in the reqesut body, I guess it will work.

Comment: It is close now ! both EMAIL and Password are defined and it is saying login successful. However the page is not redirected

Comment: What does it display when you add console.log(req.body)?

Comment: Its almost been cracked as that means it is now inside of the if statement. Just the page is not redirected

Comment: @coderStew that's another problem, we solved the main problem. Please consider to upvote and check as answer.

Comment: Even after your update it they were still not define so i set the var as "var Email = req.body.email;
    var Password = req.body.password; "  which solved that

Comment: with console.log req body it is now showing the correct email and password. But for some reason it just does not redirect the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205947/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-coderstew).

Answer (score 0):

You might try this code, I believe this should login successfully. I've also modified to connect to the database only once, rather than on each login attempt.

```
// Modify as appropriate..
const config = {
    user: 'some_user',
    password: 'some_password',
    server: 'some_server', 
    database: 'some_db' 
};

const dbConnectionPromise = sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
    console.log("Database connected successfully");
    return pool
}).catch(err => { 
    console.error("Database connection failed:", err);
});


app.post("/login", async function(req, response) {
    console.log("/login");
    await dbConnectionPromise;

    var request = new sql.Request();
    var Email = req.body.email;
    var Password = req.body.password;

    request.input("email", sql.VarChar, Email);
    request.input("password", sql.VarChar, Password);

    var queryString = "SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = @Email AND password = @Password";
    request.query(queryString, function(err, queryResult) {
        if (err) { 
            response.status(500).send(err);
        } else if (queryResult.recordset.length <= 0) {
            response.status(400).send("Incorrect email and/or Password!");
        } else if (queryResult.recordset[0].Email.length > 0) {
            console.info("/login: login successful..");
            req.session.loggedin = true;
            req.session.email = Email;
            response.redirect("/home");
        } 
    });
});

console.log(`Express listening on port: ${port}`);
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time the error it now throws is "Database connection failed: TypeError: The "config.server" property is required and must be of type string."

Comment: Apologies, I need to update the answer, I forgot to pass the config object to the sql.connect() call..

Comment: Hi thanks for the update this is now the error " TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: Cool, did you set the config properties up for your login database? Thanks!

Comment: yeah my config is all set up and is working for other routes

Comment: Ok, cool. There was another error in the code (my fault!)... now this is the code path for an incorrect email and / or password. So maybe check those as well. In any case I've corrected to send back an appropriate response in this case..